# Why is my listview.builder not updating with setstate in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate

```
class _ProjectDrawerState extends State<ProjectDrawer> {


@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    bool showMore = false;
    print('ls Length --- ${widget.ls.length}');
    void toggleShowMore()
    {
      print('Inside toggleshowMore original value --- $showMore');
      setState(() {
        showMore = !showMore;
      });
      print('Inside toggleshowMOre updated value --- $showMore');
    }
    return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(
            left: 0.04 * width,
            right: 0.04 * width,
            top: 0.14 * height,
            bottom: 0.1 * height),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: const Color(0xffefefef),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.037 * width),
        ),
        child:  SingleChildScrollView(
              child: IntrinsicHeight(
                child: ResponsiveRowColumnItem(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        height: /*showMore ? (widget.ls.length * height * 0.025) :*/ height * 0.25,
                                  child: ListView.builder(
                                    physics:
                                        const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                    itemCount: showMore ? widget.ls.length : 4,
                                    itemBuilder:
                                        (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                      print('ShowMore value inside ListView.builder  --- $showMore');
                                      return SingleChildScrollView(
                                        child: ListTile(
                                          dense: true,
                                          title: Row(
                                            children: [
                                              SizedBox(
                                                width: width * 0.0255,
                                              ),
                                              Image.asset(
                                                  'assets/logo.png',
                                                  width: 24,
                                                  height: 24),
                                              Text(
                                                '        ${widget.ls[index]}',
                                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                                style: const TextStyle(
                                                    color: Colors.black,
                                                    fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                                                    fontSize: 18,
                                                    letterSpacing: 0,
                                                    fontWeight:
                                                        FontWeight.normal,
                                                    height: 1),
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      );
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ),
                      MaterialButton(
                        onPressed: toggleShowMore,
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            SizedBox(
                              width: width * 0.22,
                              child: const Divider(
                                  color: Color(0xffbdbdbd),
                                  thickness: 1.5,
                                  height: 0.05),
                            ),
                            Text(
                              showMore ? 'See Less' : 'See more',
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                                fontSize: 18,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                color: Color(0xff000000),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Icon(
                              showMore ? Icons.arrow_drop_up_sharp : Icons.arrow_drop_down_sharp,
                              color: Colors.black,
                              size: 40,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: width * 0.2,
                              child: const Divider(
                                  color: Color(0xffbdbdbd),
                                  thickness: 1.5,
                                  height: 0.05),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),

                 
                ],
            ),
          ),
        )),
      
    ),
  ));
```

}
}

I added print statements for debugging, inside setState showMore updates to true. But why does setstate not update showmore value to true inside listview.builder and print all items inside list ls? It only prints 4 items by default, but after clicking setstate no change occurs, more elements are not rendered as it's expected to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

move your variable and function outside build method

```
    bool showMore = false;
    print('ls Length --- ${widget.ls.length}');
    void toggleShowMore()
    {
      print('Inside toggleshowMore original value --- $showMore');
      setState(() {
        showMore = !showMore;
      });
      print('Inside toggleshowMOre updated value --- $showMore');
    }

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
   .....
```

by calling `setState` it means we re-execute this method : `Widget build(BuildContext context)`.

if you put your variable inside it, then the value will be reset to the initial value that you declare